# how to use..commands

Tags: loops

Here is what I did. I need 5 random numbers so the first command is okay. After that I want the Probability formula, but I could't write it correctly.
I need to find the Probability of each of the five random numbers. and after that I need to find the probabilities of all the n numbers from 1 to 89 and do a graphic like this one here..

Comment: Why delete the code in this question?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg it is wrong

Comment: but it showed what you were trying, which helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`prod(1:365)` (e.g., 365!) evaluates to `Inf` so this will not work. Rather, use this:

```
b <- function(n) 1 - prod(365:(365-(n-1))/365)
```

This takes advantage of two facts:

1. 365!/(365-n)! = prod(365, 364, ..., 365-(n-1)), that is, the product of only n terms.
2. Each of those terms is divided by 365 (via 365^n in the denominator).

So the result is the same as: prod(1,364/365,363/365,..., (365-(n-1))/365)). This product is calculable.

But there is an additional problem: to use this function in `plot(...)` it must be "vectorized", that is it must take a vector as argument and return a vector of the same length as a result. To do that, use the `Vectorize(...)` function in R.

```
b <- Vectorize(function(n) 1 - prod(365:(365-(n-1))/365))
```

now you can use `plot(...)`

```
plot(1:89,b(1:89), type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: With the definition of `b(...)` above, `b(sample(5:50,5))`

Comment: You really need to read an intro to R. [This](http://www.statmethods.net/) is a good one. Use: `s <- sample(5:50,5); data.frame(n=s, Pn=b(s))` This will display a table of n vs. Pn.

Comment: Using these commands got this error: `> s <- sample(5:50,5)
> s
[1] 37 36 41  8 31
> data.frame(n=s, Pn=b(s))
   n       Pn
1 37 0.848734
2 36 0.848734
3 41 0.848734
4  8 0.848734
5 31 0.848734
Warning message:
In 365:(365 - (n - 1)) :
  numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used
`

Comment: Did you use the vectorized version of `b(n)`?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis in your function, should be

```
b <- function(n){
   x<- prod(1:365)
   P <- ((x)/(365^n)*(prod(1:365-n)))
   Pn <- 1-P
}
```

Comment: You don't need `return` to return a result.  That is somewhat misleading

Comment: good point, thank you

Comment: `b <- function(n) { x<- prod(1:365); 1 - ((x)/(365^n)*(prod(1:365-n))) }`

Comment: @user3009403 - this will not work.  Look at `prod(1:365)`

Comment: Now since you don't print the result of `Pn`, where is it :-)